# Causal bandstop filter

Tags: matlab, fft, filter-design

I have a vector of zeros and ones with length ~2000. I need to detect and filter out the once, that appear periodically. There may be none to 3 such periodic signal's components. Typical periods are in range 10-90, but due to measuring noise, some spikes may be shifted by 1-3 steps in any direction.

I assume there is a technique that I can set a threshold on the energy of periodical spikes, and filter them out causally. I'm not asking for a ready solution (though it would be very nice), but I would be grateful for a link to a relevant and simple example, preferably in Matlab and using FFT.

Comment: Do you have an example of the data? A plot would be ideal.

Comment: And what do you mean by *the once, that appear periodically*?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  If so, you might as well post the problem statement so we have a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish.  If not, a little more context would be helpful.  For starters, you need to define what you mean by "filtering" the periodic `1`s.  Does that mean set them all to zero? Is your output required to be binary like the input, or can it take on floating point values?

Comment: @nispio, no, this is not a homework. I studied DSP long ago in university, but now I'm asking for a shortcut to the solution.

Comment: We still can't help you much until you get more specific about what your inputs look like, and especially what you want your outputs to look like.